# Convert timestamp format to required timezone in nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a JSON file which typically consists of logs, I will be getting the logs like below. I have a field called time_stamp which contains log generated time. I want to convert that time to required timezone format in nifi. How can we achieve this.

```json
[
  {
    "time_stamp": "2023-05-10T08:00:12.390Z",
    "qid": "11188",
    "user": "writeuser",
    "level": "STATEMENT",
    "message": "  insert into ",
    "module": "database",
    "log_type": "database",
    "environment": "Development",
    "os": "linux"
  },
  {
    "time_stamp": "2023-05-10T08:00:12.366Z",
    "qid": "15841",
    "user": "writeuser",
    "level": "STATEMENT",
    "message": "  insert into ",
    "module": "database",
    "log_type": "database",
    "environment": "Development",
    "os": "linux"    
  }
]
```

Comment: Would be great if you can share if you have tried something and if you are facing any errors. Also to which timeformat are you trying to have the `Timestamp` converted to ?

Comment: I've tried using few expressions to change the attribute of time_stamp to UTC but I'm getting the same time_stamp value. I've used the below expressions like .  ${time:formatInstant("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "GMT")} but no change.

Comment: The time format is already in `UTC` format, in that case you don't need to make any changes. The `Z` in the timestamp represents its UTC

Comment: I've tried converting into IST and GMT while converting to IST I got an error like invalid timezone, and for GMT there is no change. This is where I'm confused. I'm providing a JSON which doesnt have a Z or + in it now how to change   the time_stamp here                                                                                                                          {
  "time_stamp": "2023-05-09 14:29:00",
  "service": "cassandra",
  "status": "UP",
  "pid": "2924, 3654, 3666",
  "log_type": "Service",
  "environment": "Development",
  "os": "linux"
}

Comment: You can use `format` instead as an example within a specification of JoltTransformJSON processor as `[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",                                                                                              
    "spec": {
          "time_stamp": "${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ','Europa/London')}"
    }
  }
]` , OK ?

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan, I
Tried the spec  but there is no change in the timestamp  {     "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",                                                                                                   "spec": {           "time_stamp": "${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ','UTC')}"     }   } ] .. I tried uploading the image but I am unable to do that. I tried the jolt in https://jolt-demo.appspot.com and the input and output are same

Comment: `now()` is just for testing, you might replace it with `time` as it's your parameter. Btw, the `${ }` notation is proper to NiFi, so you cannot use it within that jolt playground.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I've tried giving my time parameter (time_stamp) in nifi but there is no change in the time_stamp value, its not changing.

Comment: Notice that the second argument is not `UTC`, but should be `'<continent>/<city>'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253622/discussion-between-ram-and-barbaros-ozhan).